How to move to another activity rather than theme what we set for postsplash
My app using splashscreen api to show splashscreen which I implemented as described in docs and it's working fine splash screen is displayed and after specified time it's getting dismissed but I want to move user to another activity not SplashActivity where I added splash theme
Like user open app it will check if user is signed in or not if not it will move user to OnboardActivity else it will move to HomeActivity but unable to fix it
After trying after splashscreen disappear the SplashActivity is showing and then checking starts if user signed or not for moving to desired activity below is my code
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        initialize();
        checkMaintenanceAndRedirect();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }

    private void checkMaintenanceAndRedirect() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                apiUrl,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            String status = jsonResponse.getString("status");
                            if ("off".equals(status)) {
                                navigateToMainteActivity();
                            } else {
                                redirectToAppropriateActivity();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            navigateToMainteActivity(); // Navigate to maintenance activity as fallback
                        }
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        navigateToMainteActivity(); // Navigate to maintenance activity as fallback
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void redirectToAppropriateActivity() {
        FirebaseUser currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser != null) {
            navigateToHomeActivity();
        } else {
            navigateToOnboardActivity();
        }
    }

    private void navigateToHomeActivity() {
        Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(ii);
        finish();
    }

    private void navigateToOnboardActivity() {
        Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OnboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(ii);
        finish();
    }

    private void navigateToMainteActivity() {
        Intent im = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainteActivity.class);
        startActivity(im);
        finish();
    }
}


what is the main error or problem in your code?
I have go through your code, Its looking fine.
please tell the main task you want to do.

Actually I don't to show splashscreen as in my code after the splashscreen is dismissed the SplashActivity is been shown up which I don't want I want users to navigate directly to either HomeActivity or OnboardActivity as soon as the splash screen gets dismiss

To do this you need to remove SplashActivity and use other activity as Launcher. Implement splash logic there and use setKeepOnScreenCondition to wait until it's done.

Here is the complete guideline.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate
